# Loading GIF on normal form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I don't know if this is possible because according to my concept it is not.Say I have a form:

```
<form action="/loadLotsOfRecords" method="get">
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit />
</form>
```

Now this form takes at least 10-15 seconds to load because of obviously there are lots of record. I know using AJAX i can make a loading GIF and load the records. But is there a way in which without using AJAX I can simply show a GIF in those 15 seconds when the page is loading. If I use windows.load function it only spins on the next page. What I require is instead of browser loading I want a simultaneous loader on my body. Thanks

Comment: The quick answer is... No. The problem is that when you submit a form/browse to a new page, you have no control over the page anymore. The browser is then waiting to get the response from the server. Until that happens, you need to wait and let the browser do it's thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You simply need to show you loader gif on successful form submission. In this way, the loading gif appears on the page and keeps displaying until the page is redirected to next page after processing. You don't care about hiding the loading unless you are expecting any error in form submission. You should show this loader, only when form has been successfully submitted.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").on("submit", function(){
    $("#pageloader").fadeIn();
  });//submit
});//document ready
```

```css
#pageloader
{
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 );
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#pageloader img
{
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pageloader">
   <img src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.16.1/images/loader-large.gif" alt="processing..." />
</div>

<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Well, many (most) browsers actually stops gif animations etc. when it starts to navigate to a new page. So, sure it _might_ work in some specific situations, but in general, it's not really a _solution_.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You have a point there. But I have used it a couple of times and it worked. Might be I didn't check in all browsers.

Comment: ...and I use to do it and stopped because it seldom worked. :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think you are right because last time I tried on mozilla it didn't work maybe what you said is the reason

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson. I will also have to stop using this then ;)

Comment: It does not work with client side validations.

Comment: @AjayTakur currently the code only shows the gif on submit (and does not hide it). If you want it with client validation, you can show it before running validation and hide it again if the validation fails.

Answer (score 2):

- You need to use setTimeout function in java script as it enables your
  loader to load without other elements in your web page being
  highlighted.
       Purpose of using AJAX is to load required data behind    the scenes, that is the reason why your browser tries to
  display all    the other elements in a the page.

  ```
        setTimeout(function(){
          Loader.show();  
              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                   url: "XXXXXXX.htm",

                   data: { your_data},
                   success:function(result)
                   {
                       Loader.hide();
                   },
                   complete:function(){
                       Loader.hide();
                   },
                   error:function(){
                       Loader.hide();
                   }
                   });

          },1);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").on("submit", function(){
    $("#preloder").fadeIn();
  });//submit
});//document ready
```

```css
/* Preloder */

#preloder {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
    /* background: #000; */
    background: #ffffff;
}

.loader {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;      
        /* border: 4px solid #f44336; */
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        /* border: 4px solid #673ab7; */
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page Preloder -->
<div id="preloder">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to display a block page using blockUi Js they will be block full page when you click on the submit button you just write submit button click event globally.

```js
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(':submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            StartBlockPage()
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
  StartBlockPage()
});

function StartBlockPage() {
    var block_body = $("#body");
    $(block_body).block({
        message: '<div class="fa fa-spinner spinner spinner--steps2 font-large-5"></div><br /><br /><h2>Please wait until the server responds.</h2>',
        overlayCSS: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            opacity: 0.8,
            cursor: 'wait',
            height: '200vh'
        },
        css: {
            border: 0,
            padding: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        }
    });
}

function CloseBlockPage() {
    var block_body = $("#body");
    $(block_body).unblock();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<html>
<body id="body">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(':submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            StartBlockPage()
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
  StartBlockPage()
});

function StartBlockPage() {
    var block_body = $("#body");
    $(block_body).block({
        message: '<div class="fa fa-spinner spinner spinner--steps2 font-large-5"></div><br /><br /><h2>Please wait until the server responds.</h2>',
        overlayCSS: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            opacity: 0.8,
            cursor: 'wait',
            height: '200vh'
        },
        css: {
            border: 0,
            padding: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        }
    });
}

function CloseBlockPage() {
    var block_body = $("#body");
    $(block_body).unblock();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<html>
<body id="body">
</body>
</html>
```