# How to show a page loading after a particular tab in the multi-step form until an alert shows up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a multi-step form which contains 4 steps. When the 3rd step is submitted an alert comes in for successful submission. So, until the alert comes up I want to show a loading page. So, how can I do so ?

Thank you

I searched a lot for loading page, but it is for until the page loads. And in this form I want to show the loading page until an alert comes up.

Comment: Unclear that do you want (my answer will be - "ok, add loading page after 3rd step, it is not a problem for you, because you know how to add loading page beafore all things").

Just give me more tips - what fontend lib do you use? Is it JQuery? Is it React or Angular or Vue? May be you do not use javascript at all?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple,
you need to show your loader page on successful form submission, the loading page will appear on the page and keeps displaying until the page is redirected to the next page after processing.

simple you can do it like this in js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").on("submit", function(){
    $("#pageloader").fadeIn();
  });//submit done
});//document ready
```

refer this post - [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38217386/10180766)